# Are there events defined in the word vba object model for these events?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

First of all, I did look and did not find any.

I want a macro to run whenever one of the following happens:

1. The document is opened
2. The document is saved
3. Text is pasted into the document
4. The document grows to one page more.
5. The document shrinks to one page less.

For the first 2 there are events, even if technically the second is before save, but are there for the other three? If not, can I somehow add them?

With regards to event number two, is there a DocumentBeforeSave event also when autosaving?

Comment: Not exactly, the total pagecount of the whole document. Sometimes people will want to print only a part of it for review. That would change the print area but not the total number of pages.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about capturing/intercepting commands. You're right, there are events for `open` and `save`, but the others are less common. Here is a link to some code to [Catch Paste](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/CatchPaste.asp). I know if focuses on Excel, but it can help you go in the right direction for what you are trying to do.

Also, check out [Using VBA to Control Built-In Commands in the 2007 Office System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627337%28v=office.12%29.aspx). There is a link in this article to [SDK Documentation and References for Office Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905496.aspx) which could also be helpful.

*Keep in mind; running macros on a saved document may not work the same for each person unless Macro Security is set the same. Some computers may have them blocked which will mean your document will not act as you desire.*

Comment: I don't think the suggestion to catch the paste event will work as from memory Application.OnKey doesn't work in MS Word.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can override certain VBA functions by naming the sub the same as the in-built method name. In this case this should help serve as capturing the event.

```
Sub EditPaste()

Selection.Paste
'Other code

End Sub
```

Regarding capturing the number of pages in the document, you could use a timer to poll the number of pages and act if the count has changed:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), _
Name:="CheckPages"

End Sub

Sub CheckPages()

'
' Get pages using ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Pages.Count 
' Compare with page count stored via global variable
' If they don't match run code for your event.

'Rerun the macro in 1 second
Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), _
Name:="CheckPages"

End Sub
```